# Microsoft Bot Web Chat Not working but Emulator work fine

Tags: botframework

I have created a bot application and published it to azure. When I test this bot using Emulator it works fine but when I use the web chat control it doesn't show anything . I am using the correct app-secret .
The link to web chat is [here](https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/BingSearchAndEmotionApiBot?s=kLn6I1NkWwk.cwA.cHg.W2KHTZY6oiUMqdKgYvj1NjGpElpq3OqP27Jat7jb4Gg) . My bot is hosted on azure .Here is the link of Message Endpoint= https://bingsearchandemotionbotv3.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Comment: Any update on this issue for the ones who faced issue?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check: If you go into your bot management page on https://dev.botframework.com/bots and press the blue "Test" button on the bottom left ("Test connection to your bot"), does it indicate that the bot accepts the connection by the bot framework middleware?

If not, then there might be something wrong with your bot. It will actually give you some indications. If it's "forbidden", then you might have a problem with authentication (check your appId and appPassword). If it's an error, then your bot might have a code issue / exception.

If the connection has been accepted, check if your web chat credentials have been validated. To do so, click on the "Edit" link next to the Web Chat channel on the bot management page. Try regenerating your credentials and (most importantly) make sure you checked "Enable this bot on Web Chat" and confirm.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Is it because the bot is in review? Testing the endpoint gives the message "Endpoint authorization succeeded.".  Web chat is configured, running, and enabled.  The iframe to embed works and I get the greeting, but after sending messages I get no responses.  Also, the greeting doesn't come when the bot is in the emulator.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I hit the same thing - I am able to execute the .js code, but the response does not appear in the web chat.